# Correct dim parameter in tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, dim, epsilon=1e-12, name=None) for RGB picture

Tags: python, tensorflow, normalization

I want to use tensorflows

```
tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, dim, epsilon=1e-12, name=None)
```

method to normalize each channel seperately in a (32x32x3) RGB image.

How do I have to set the

```
dim
```

parameter to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation, [`tf.nn.l2_normalize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/normalization#l2_normalize),

> For x with more dimensions, independently normalizes each 1-D slice along dimension dim.

Since your channel is the third dimension, you can pass in `dim=2` (since dimensions start from 0).

Answer (score 0):

You should set `dim = [0, 1]`.
So each channel `[32, 32]` would be normalized as `[32*32]`, a 1-D tensor.